# Не могу понять пример из учебника Django Mozilla!

Tags: python-3.x, django

Создайте шаблон, на который ссылается наше отображение (/catalog/templates/catalog/book_renew_librarian.html) и скопируйте в него код, указаный ниже:

```
    {% extends "base_generic.html" %}
{% block content %}

    <h1>Renew: {{bookinst.book.title}}</h1>
    <p>Borrower: {{bookinst.borrower}}</p>
    <p{% if bookinst.is_overdue %} class="text-danger"{% endif %}>Due date: {{bookinst.due_back}}</p>

    <form action="" method="post">
        {% csrf_token %}
        <table>
        {{ form }}
        </table>
            <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
        </form>

    {% endblock %}
```

Все что осталось, это указать переменную {{form}}, которую мы передали в шаблон в словаре контекста. Возможно это вас не удивит, но таким образом мы предоставим возможность форме отрендерить свои поля с их метками, виджетами и дополнительными текстами, и в результате мы получим следующее:

```
    <tr>
  <th><label for="id_renewal_date">Renewal date:</label></th>
  <td>
    <input id="id_renewal_date" name="renewal_date" type="text" value="2016-11-08" required />
    <br />
    <span class="helptext">Enter date between now and 4 weeks (default 3 weeks).</span>
  </td>
</tr>
```

Если вы ввели неправильную дату, то на странице вы должны получить список сообщений об ошибках (показано жирным ниже).

```
    <tr>
  <th><label for="id_renewal_date">Renewal date:</label></th>
   <td>
      <ul class="errorlist">
        <li>Invalid date - renewal in past</li>
      </ul>
      <input id="id_renewal_date" name="renewal_date" type="text" value="2015-11-08" required />
      <br />
      <span class="helptext">Enter date between now and 4 weeks (default 3 weeks).</span>
    </td>
</tr>
```

Не могу понять где я должен ввести куски кода с тэгами  в мануале непонятно объяснено?.Это одна из последних глав книги,но понимание форм пока так и не пришло.Посоветуйте где посмотреть!

Comment: Не могу понять где я должен ввести куски кода с тэгами<tr> в мануале непонятно объяснено?.Это одна из последних глав книги,но понимание форм пока так и не пришло.Посоветуйте где посмотреть!

Comment: Первый блок кода из вашего сообщения - это код, который нужно записать в book_renew_librarian.html . Остальные - это примеры из уже отрендеренной страницы, а именно из формы, созданной тэгом {{ form }}